# Switch to another input method

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I can't find anything clear of how linux is handling the keyboard. (system based configurations not gui)

My problem is : I installed `ibus` on a `linux mint` with several languages but it just doesn't work, despite `ibus-setup`, `ibus-daemon -rx`...

Maybe my system is using another input method than `ibus` ?
Is there a command to know which input method my computer is actually using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input method used (IM) is actually set in `~/.xinputrc`.

Run the command `im-config` to choose your input method.

Or maybe simply add manually `run_im ibus` inside your `~/.xinputrc` : It is what `im-config` is doing.

Of course you need to restart X.

Comment: its work for me, thank you !